# iPhone Pull to Refresh Move Icon Position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I have my scroll view span the whole height of the iPhone. Thus, the iPhone's semi-transparent status bar is overlayed on top of the scroll view. I've added iOS6's UIRefreshControl to the scroll view, like so:

```
UIRefreshControl *pullToRefresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[pullToRefresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = pullToRefresh;
[self.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Everything functionally works great. However, the pull to refresh icon doesn't pull down low enough to clear the iPhone status bar. This looks junky, like so:

[image: Pull to Refresh]

I've tried setting the frame/bounds on the UIRefreshControl to reposition the refresh icon, but no luck. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913208/uitableview-with-uirefreshcontrol-under-a-semi-transparent-status-bar

Comment: you need to change the position of UIScrollview instead..

Comment: the scrollview goes behind status bar as your statusbar is transparent.

Comment: Yup, Sharanya, you are correct. That answer (by subclassing UIRefreshControl) works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a contentInset of 20 px at the top. That is a property on UIScrollView.